# Mudar css através de nome / url (Sem ID ou class)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Queria saber um script que ao ver link e nome na pagina html muda o estilo...

Preciso conseguir um script que dê para mim colocar alguns links e nomes dos comentarios ou só um dos 2, precisaria de um lugar nesse script pra mim colocar meu css personalizado para cada link/nome, e se der pra customizar é melhor ainda, pra mim colocar uns 20 com o mesmo css junto e os outros separados

ou

Um script que coloque um ID para nomes

Detalhando:
É para comentários de blog, queria diferenciar o ADM, Membros e visitantes, entao antes de criar os styles precisaria conseguir tornar isso possível

Abaixo é o padrão de como está os links atuais (pra quem ve de fora): todo comentario tem o mesmo class="fn" se mudar muda pra todos, da mesma forma que se tentar colocar um id no link me ajudem...

```
<cite class="fn">
<a href="LINK" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="Gabriel Miller">Gabriel Miller</a>
</cite>
```

Comment: Não sei se te ajuda a princípio porque a pergunta ficou meio confusa, mas você pode usar CSS dessa forma: `a[title="Gabriel Miller"] { /* seu css */ }`

Comment: não deu certo nao, talvez ficou meio confusa a pergunta pq tentei explicar perfeitamente o que queria...

Comment: Você queria chamar o script com base em qual dos atributos do link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos lá, pelo que entendi você precisa primeiramente criar as classes que vai dar vida a tudo, com as classes criadas agora você precisa verificar através do link e adicionar para cada 'cargo' sua classe respectiva, vou levar em consideração que o link existe uma palavra com o cargo.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $( "a" ).each(function() {
    switch($(this).attr('href')){
      case 'administrador':
        $( this ).parent().parent().addClass( "adm" );
      break;
      case 'moderador':
        $( this ).parent().parent().addClass( "mod" );
      break;
      case 'membro':
        $( this ).parent().parent().addClass( "memb" );
      break;
      
    }
    
  });
});
```

```css
.container{
  float:left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #CCC;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.adm{
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.mod{
  border: 3px solid gold;
}

.memb{
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <cite class="fn">
    <a href="moderador" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="Gabriel Miller">Gabriel Miller</a>
  </cite>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <cite class="fn">
      <a href="administrador" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="Gabriel Miller">Gabriel Miller</a>
  </cite>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <cite class="fn">
      <a href="membro" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="Gabriel Miller">Gabriel Miller</a>
  </cite>
</div>
```

Se errei em algo ou não esclareci corretamente, pode comentar abaixo.

Comment: PERFEITOOO vc é o cara Mateus muito obrigada